# How to suspend and resume browser tab groups?

Tags: browser, tabs, webpage

Modern browsers such as Firefox and Chrome are able to shutdown and restore the same group of tabs they had before the next time you open them, and even sometimes remember additional tab state such as scroll position within the tab.

I would like ideally to be able to select a group of tabs (about some coherent theme, perhaps) and save them away into some kind of "folder" that I could later open *independently, without opening any other tabs*. Obviously I can use bookmarks for this, but bookmarks are kind of old-fashioned. It would be excellent if it could also record forms that I had filled in but not submitted, scroll position, tab position within the tab group, and any other "dynamic" aspects of the current tab state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not exactly the same, but the following two things can achieve a similar effect on Google Chrome:

1. Enable the experimental Tab Groups feature in chrome://flags, and restart Chrome for the change to take effect. You can now right-click on any tab and add it to a Tab Group, and the Tab Groups will be kept around when you next restart Chrome, if you are running a recent version of Chrome.
2. Install [The Great Suspender](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg/related?hl=en). This will *automatically* suspend *any* tabs you haven't used for a while - regardless of whether they are in the tab group you just created. It can be configured to not suspend tabs with unsubmitted data in form inputs, too, so that you won't lose any data.

Answer (score 5):

Use [Session Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-manager/) add-on of Firefox. You can find many for Chrome, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Chrome extension called [Tab Cloud](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabcloud/npecfdijgoblfcgagoijgmgejmcpnhof) that synchronizes tab groups across all Chrome installations. It's the only extension I've found (so far) that is able to do this.